# Refer to part of table VBA

Tags: vba

I don't know how to refer to part of a table in VBA.

Currently I have this code - which work - but I want to refer to the range "c3:t23" within the table. Not the entire table or the databody.

```
If Not Intersect(ActiveCell, [Table2]) Is Nothing Then
```

If anyone knows, or knows some where that describes it really well then don't hesitate - Thanks

Comment: `[Table2]` needs to be `range(c3:t23)`

Comment: Can I make it into an active range? so if I add another row the function that I apply on the table will take the new row into account?

Comment: Select the your range then create a named range and change the code to ``If Not Intersect(ActiveCell, range("YournamedRange") Is Nothing Then``

Comment: Does `c3:t23` equate to whole columns within the table?  This link may help: [The VBA Guide To ListObject Excel Tables](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables)